# Can I remove .listing files from web subdirectories?

Tags: linux, sftp

I was working on my webserver, and noticed I wasn't able to remove a directory as it wasn't empty. I ran `ls` in it, and found a single `.listing` file. Opening it, I found a list of the files that were once in the directory, which was now out of date. The file suggested that the now-deleted files belonged to the `ftp` user. This leads me to believe the listing file was copied from my old shared web host, as the current server is not running an FTP server (although SSH/SFTP *is*). I looked around further, and found that almost all web-facing directories have a `.listing` file in them.

Having looked on the web, it seems they are created by an FTP server, but I can't find much more information than that. I found that `wget` supports an argument which prevents `wget` from *not* downloading them, but I didn't find anything saying whether they could be removed. My guess it that they can.

Can I safely remove the `.listing` files littered throughout my website directories?

Answer (score 2):

gnu.org contains this information (and more) in [the wget FTP Options manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/FTP-Options.html) in the description for the `--no-remove-listing` option:

> Normally, these files contain the raw directory listings received from FTP servers. Not removing them can be useful for debugging purposes, or when you want to be able to easily check on the contents of remote server directories (e.g. to verify that a mirror you’re running is complete).